# How to create user profiles with Bottle and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, bottle, user-profile

I want to set up user profiles in a `Python` app that is using `Bottle` and `MongoDB`.

I've searched for:

```
create users profile in bottle python
```

But the majority of links relate to `Flask`.

I'm new to Bottle and need a `'from the ground up'` introduction to the particular topic of `user profiles` in `Bottle`.

I understand that routes are used to trigger functions, and have got several of these routes and functions working.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could provide a newbie friendly guide to understanding and implementing `user profiles` within the `Bottle` framework in a `MongoDB` environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of authentication mechanisms for Bottle that I've seen. You could attempt to use those user accounts as a starting point to build out a more robust profile.

- Cork (authentication): http://cork.firelet.net/
- Bottle example user accounts: https://github.com/uvtc/bottle-example-user-accounts

  - This one might get you closer to what you need but will still require some work to integrate with MongoDB.